# Is there a term for sounds that are spelled with multiple letters?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word or term to describe sounds (phonemes) that are spelled using multiple characters (graphemes)? Examples would include the English ch, sh, or German dsch, tsch, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was in elementary school, these were called [(consonant) blends](https://longmanhomeusa.com/blog/teaching-consonant-blends-digraphs-and-trigraphs/):

> A consonant blend (also called a consonant cluster) is a group of two or three consonants in words that makes a distinct consonant sound, such as bl, br, cl, cr, dr, fl, fr, gl, gr, pl, pr, qu, sc, sk, sl, sm, sn, sp, st, sw, tr, and tw

The more technical terms for this are [digraph, trigraph, quadgraph](https://www.thrassafrica.co.za/definitions), etc.

Comment: I think digraph, trigraph, etc... is what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: From a programming background, hearing about digraphs and trigraphs in English is odd.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the same in every discipline, but in [speech synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis) (a computer turning written text to speech) each sound as you've described is called a [phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)).  An adjacent pair of phones create [diphones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphone), and the same diphone can be pronounced differently depending on context.  Specifically, a sound without any vowels is a [consonant cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_cluster).